# linq group by multipe aggregates

Tags: sql, linq

Im new to Linq and Im sure that I have gone about this in a convoluted manner.  Im trying to do something like this SQL in Linq:

`SELECT DISTINCT

   count(vendor) as vendorCount, 

   reqDate, 

   status, 

   openDate, 

   item, 

   poDate, 

   count(responseDate) as responseCount 

FROM 

   myTable

GROUP BY 

   reqDate, status, openDate, item, poDate

HAVING

   reqDate > openDate`

Here is what I have so far.

```
        var groupQuery = (from table in dt.AsEnumerable()
                         group table by new
                         {                                 
                             vendor = table["vendor"], reqdate = table.Field<DateTime>("ReqDate"), status = table["status"],
                             open = table["openDate"],  
                             item = table["item"), 
                             podate = table.Field<DateTime>("PODate"), responsedate =  table.Field<DateTime>("responseDate"), 
                         }
                             into groupedTable
                             where Having(groupedTable.Key.reqdate, groupedTable.Key.openDate) == 1
                             select new
                             {
                                 x = groupedTable.Key,  
                                 y = groupedTable.Count()
                             }).Distinct();



        foreach (var req in groupQuery)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("cols: {0} count: {1} ",
                req.x, req.y);
        }
```

The Having() is a function that takes two datetime parameters and returns a 1 if the reqDate is greater than the openDate.  It compiles and runs, but it obviously does not give me the results I want.  Is this possible using Linq?  I want to push this data to an excel spreadsheet so Im hoping to create a datatable from this linq query.  Would I be better off just creating a dataview from my datatable and not mess with Linq?

Comment: One thing I see is you are grouping by `vendor` and `responsedate`.  Remove those to create the proper groupings.  The only thing I'm unsure of is what you want the count of.  Do you want the count of each grouping, or do you want the count of the distinct vendors and the count of the distinct responsedates of each grouping?

Comment: Remove vendor and responseDate from my linq statement?

Comment: I want the count of the vendors and responsedates of each grouping.  (Someone else wrote the sql so I am assuming some things about the data.)  Right now my results are always count: 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL code is grouping by only some of the fields, while your LINQ statement is grouping by all of the fields, so the only items that would get grouped would be duplicates.  If you group by only the fields that the SQL query groups by, you should get the correct answer.  Your `Having()` method words fine, but is not necessary and is less readable.

```
var groupQuery = (from table in dt.AsEnumerable()
                 group table by new
                 {                                 
                     reqdate = table.Field<DateTime>("ReqDate"),
                     status = table["status"],
                     open = table["openDate"],  
                     item = table["item"), 
                     podate = table.Field<DateTime>("PODate")
                 }
                 into groupedTable
                 where groupedTable.Key.reqdate > groupedTable.Key.openDate
                 select new
                 {
                     x = groupedTable.Key,  
                     VenderCount = groupedTable.Select(t => t["vendor"])
                                               .Distinct()
                                               .Count(),
                     ResponseCount = groupedTable.Select(t => t.Field<DateTime>("responseDate"))
                                                 .Distinct()
                                                 .Count()
                 }).Distinct();
```

Comment: The Having() actually does a lot more, but I simplified it for this example since it was working.  I took out the vendor and responseDate, but I dont see a vendorCount or responseCount returned in my foreach.  How can I get those?

Comment: Should y = groupedTabletable.Select.Field<DateTime>("responseDate").Count be y = groupedTable.Select.Field<DateTime>("responseDate").Count?  It looks like an extra "table" got put in there.  I assume so.  I took it out but I get a syntax error on the Select - ArgumentNullException.

Comment: I changed it to y = groupedTable.Select(t => t.Field<DateTime>("DtTm Resp")).Count() and it compiles now.  I still need to look over the results a bit...

Comment: @rahkim: Sorry, I forgot to take that out.

Comment: This looks good.  One question:  Why is there a Distinct on each aggregate and the select?  Can I take out the one on the select?

Comment: @rahkim It will remove duplicates before counting.  If that isn't an issue then the count will always be the group's count, so you could just write `VenderCount = groupedTable.Count()` and `ResponseCount = groupedTable.Count()`.